# Google Analyitcs tracking after form submit

Tags: google-analytics, hubspot

I am trying to add the Google Analytics tracking code to a hubspot page. However the tracking should **ONLY** happen, if and when the user has submitted a form.

I have been searching around for a while, and as I see it, this is a more difficult task, than it needs to be? have you found a nice solution to this?

My thoughts (after I found out that I couldn't add code to the submit button), was to create a "thank-you" landingpage and redirecting to it after submit, and then send tracking from there - But my client really wants the "inline thank you" message -

Can I please hear your thoughts and ideas, since I'm new to hubspot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HubSpot does a have a callback method for submit. You could trigger your analytics from the Analytics JS API - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

```
hbspt.forms.create({ 
css: '',
onFormSubmit: function(){
      ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
   }
});
```